# AttributeError: module 'socks' has no attribute 'SOCKS5'

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.5

I'm currently running `python 3.5.1` and `SocksiPy-branch==1.1`

I'm trying to run this

```
import socket
import socks
import requests

r = requests.get('http://gimmeproxy.com/api/getProxy?protocol=socks5&maxCheckPeriod=3600').json()
try:
  sdp = socks.set_default_proxy
except AttributeError:
  sdp = socks.setdefaultproxy
sdp(socks.SOCKS5, r['ip'], int(r['port']))
socket.socket = socks.socksocket
```

Not sure why this isn't working? I keep getting `AttributeError: module 'socks' has no attribute 'SOCKS5'`

Comment: Did you try https://github.com/Anorov/PySocks ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The library doesn't define any such constant, it defines:

```
PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS4 = 1
PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5 = 2
PROXY_TYPE_HTTP = 3
```

Also it seems to be unmaintained since 2010. There is a more recent version, [PySocks](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PySocks). If your code is based on an example/tutorial, it was probably using that library as it defines:

```
PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS4 = SOCKS4 = 1
PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5 = SOCKS5 = 2
PROXY_TYPE_HTTP = HTTP = 3
```

Comment: So he could try `socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5` instead of `socks.SOCKS5` according to your research without using the newer fork/version...I would go for the new fork anyway, at least is maintained ;)  And there is an example in the original SocksiPy README using `socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5`. As you mention, I think he looked at the "new" example while using the "old" module.